# How to read text and font from .doc using Aspose Word for Java

Tags: java, ms-word, ms-office, aspose, aspose.words

I have an assignment to read and write to a ***.doc*** file and must be able to read the ***font setting*** for each word. I'm currently using `Aspose` word for Java in my development, the write to word and including the font setting to each word is running. The only problem is sometimes when i try to pick a *`.doc`* file and read it using the code below, it returns nothing from the *`System.out.print`*. But also sometimes it came but with only few words rather than the whole content.

```
final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
            HomeForm form = new HomeForm();
             if (evt.getSource() == jButton2)
             {
                int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(HomeForm.this);
                File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File " +file.getName()+" choosed", "Alert", JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION);
                        jTextField1.setText(file.getName());

                        String dataDir = file.getPath();
                        String filename = file.getName();

                    try {
                        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(dataDir);
                        Document doc = new Document(in);
                        System.out.println(file.getName());;
                        System.out.println(doc.getText());
                        in.close();FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());Logger.getLogger(HomeForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);InputStreamReader(fis, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(HomeForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(HomeForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File choose canceled", "Alert", JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION);
                    }
                 }
```

Am i heading toward a right direction by using this code for *reading each word* and each *word font setting*? Or maybe Aspose can't handle these kind of processings? Please help, thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this framework but if you mean the *settings* like font sizes, family, bold/italic, etc. , then I don't see those parts in your code, from what I can see, you just read the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Aspose.Words for Java API](https://www.aspose.com/products/words/java) to get text and Font name of each Run in Document by using the following code:

```
Document doc = new Document("D:\temp\in.doc");

for(Run run : (Iterable) doc.getChildNodes(NodeType.RUN, true)) {
    System.out.println(run.getText());
    System.out.println(run.getFont().getName());
}
```

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: If it's the Font Spacing, can i get it too?

Comment: You can use Font.Spacing property to retrieve or set the spacing (in points) between characters.